# How to effectively compare two datasets for differences?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a couple queries that presents a number of data-points about the structure of our database, one for the Tables and other for the Views:

Tables:

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , c.COLUMN_NAME
    , c.ORDINAL_POSITION
    , c.COLUMN_DEFAULT
    , c.IS_NULLABLE
    , c.DATA_TYPE
    , c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    , c.NUMERIC_PRECISION
    , c.NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX
    , c.NUMERIC_SCALE
    , ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
    , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , rc.MATCH_OPTION
    , rc.DELETE_RULE
    , rc.UPDATE_RULE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu ON (c.TABLE_NAME = ccu.TABLE_NAME AND c.COLUMN_NAME = ccu.COLUMN_NAME)
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc ON ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Views:

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS 'VIEW_SCHEMA'
    , t.TABLE_NAME AS 'VIEW_NAME'
    , c.COLUMN_NAME
    , c.ORDINAL_POSITION
    , c.COLUMN_DEFAULT
    , c.IS_NULLABLE
    , c.DATA_TYPE
    , c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'
```

My intent here is that I can run the queries against our Production environment and save the output as a "snapshot". Then later on when we make changes in our Development environment, I can run the queries there, and grab another "snapshot". With the current vs changes snapshots I could then compare them against each other to analyze the differences.

Note: Yes, I am aware things like RedGate and such have tools like this, but third-party tools are not an option for me where I am at... and secondly the end goal is to have something I can turn into a report that can be sent via email or in a PDF or whatever.

I am choosing to anchor everything on the Table/Column pair as a "primary key", as this seems the best way to tell if there is a new/removed/changed column, and the results of my query are saved into two tables: `[Meta].[SchemaChanges_New]` and `[Meta].[SchemaChanges_Current]`. I am not including the Table's schema as I want to know if this is a change, versus using it in the JOIN where it would then cause the change to identify as a New vs Removed item.

So the query to identify new items is pretty straight forward:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM [Meta].[SchemaChanges_New] n
LEFT JOIN [Meta].[SchemaChanges_Current] c 
  ON (n.[TABLE_NAME] = c.[TABLE_NAME] AND n.[COLUMN_NAME] = c.[COLUMN_NAME])
WHERE (c.[TABLE_NAME] IS NULL OR c.[COLUMN_NAME] IS NULL)
ORDER BY n.[TABLE_NAME], n.[ORDINAL_POSITION]
```

...and the query to identify removed items equally so:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM [Meta].[SchemaChanges_Current] c
LEFT JOIN [Meta].[SchemaChanges_New] n 
  ON (c.[TABLE_NAME] = n.[TABLE_NAME] AND c.[COLUMN_NAME] = n.[COLUMN_NAME])
WHERE (n.[TABLE_NAME] IS NULL OR n.[COLUMN_NAME] IS NULL)
ORDER BY n.[TABLE_NAME], n.[ORDINAL_POSITION]
```

*If there are more appropriate ways to accomplish this I am all ears as well.

My dilemma is in trying to figure out the best/most efficient means to identify those items that have changed. And because I am also capturing Index information, there is the possibility of multiple changes for a given Table/Column.

First stab at the old-school "brute force" method appears to work pretty decent:

```
SELECT c.*, n.*
FROM [Meta].[SchemaChanges_New] n
INNER JOIN [Meta].[SchemaChanges_Current] c 
   ON (n.[TABLE_NAME] = c.[TABLE_NAME] AND n.[COLUMN_NAME] = c.[COLUMN_NAME])
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA != n.TABLE_SCHEMA
   OR c.ORDINAL_POSITION != n.ORDINAL_POSITION
   OR IsNull(c.COLUMN_DEFAULT, '') != IsNull(n.COLUMN_DEFAULT, '')
   OR IsNull(c.IS_NULLABLE, '') != IsNull(n.IS_NULLABLE, '')
   OR IsNull(c.DATA_TYPE, '') != IsNull(n.DATA_TYPE, '')
   OR IsNull(c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, '') != IsNull(n.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, '')
   OR IsNull(c.NUMERIC_PRECISION, '') != IsNull(n.NUMERIC_PRECISION, '')
   OR IsNull(c.NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, '') != IsNull(n.NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, '')
   OR IsNull(c.NUMERIC_SCALE, '') != IsNull(n.NUMERIC_SCALE, '')
   OR IsNull(c.CONSTRAINT_NAME, '') != IsNull(n.CONSTRAINT_NAME, '')
   OR IsNull(c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, '') != IsNull(n.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, '')
   OR IsNull(c.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME, '') != IsNull(n.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME, '')
   OR IsNull(c.MATCH_OPTION, '') != IsNull(n.MATCH_OPTION, '')
   OR IsNull(c.DELETE_RULE, '') != IsNull(n.DELETE_RULE, '')
   OR IsNull(c.UPDATE_RULE, '') != IsNull(n.UPDATE_RULE, '')
```

However I am finding that when some columns have more than one Index associated, false positives can show up due to the "simplistic" JOIN. But if I add more connections to the JOIN I risk altered items falling out of the result set.

So I am asking for help on how to approach this... so that I can identify any changes, no matter how slight, to the structure, makeup, composition, etc. of the tables/views or the Indexes associated, but also eliminate false positives due to improper matching of the records between the two snapshots.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a binary checksum composed of the columns you are interested in monitoring:

```
  binchk = binary_checksum(concat(t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                , t.TABLE_NAME
                                , c.COLUMN_NAME
                                , c.ORDINAL_POSITION
                                , c.COLUMN_DEFAULT
                                , c.IS_NULLABLE
                                , c.DATA_TYPE
                                , c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
                                , c.NUMERIC_PRECISION
                                , c.NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX
                                , c.NUMERIC_SCALE
                                , ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                , tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
                                , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                , rc.MATCH_OPTION
                                , rc.DELETE_RULE
                                , rc.UPDATE_RULE))
```

[the concat handles null values]

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand how this will help? I did what you suggest and I get a number back for each row: 298844079, 823663669, -304608905, 647659503, -2138610040, 221236130. And they are...?? Did something change? Is it the same? Can you please expand on your answer as to how to apply this and make it fit the situation I described? Thanks

Comment: Any change in a column will cause a large change in the checksum.  So the idea is to store the results in a table, along with the checksum, then after a time generate the checksum again.  A difference in the checksums means that something has changed, so then just compare the old and new column values.

Comment: Your suggestion only calls out that a change was made, not what change. Your comment "so then just compare the old and new column values" is the whole point of my post... what is the best way to identify *what* change(s) have been made. I thank you a bunch for this quick method to identify the "when", but I am asking about the "what".

Comment: Then you either manually scan, comparing column by column, or automate like you have above.  It depends what your end goal is.